# How to link opencv lib in a given directory in makefile

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I'm compiling a project and I want to link it to the opencv in a given directory, not the system directory like `/usr/local/lib/libopencv`

In the end is the default makefile, which links to the system directory `/usr/local/lib`.

The opencv I want to link is located in directory `../../third_party/opencv/`, with `../../third_party/opencv/include/` and `../../third_party/opencv/lib/`. The absolute path is `/home/somepath/third_party/opencv/`.

How shall I modify the `makefile` to have the project link to the opencv I want to use, instead of the system version?

Currently, when I compile the project and use `ldd` to check its dependency, say `ldd evaluate | grep opencv`， I got the following. It means the project still links to the system version, not my chosen one.

```
libopencv_highgui.so.3.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.0 (0x00007efc72527000)
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0 (0x00007efc7217a000)
libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.0 (0x00007efc711f8000)
libopencv_core.so.3.0 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.0 (0x00007efc70565000)
```

Thank you for helping me!!!

```
PROJECT_NAME:= evaluate

# config ----------------------------------

INCLUDE_DIRS := include
LIBRARY_DIRS := lib

COMMON_FLAGS := -DCPU_ONLY
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0

LDFLAGS := -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath,./lib

OPENCV = `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
LIB = $(OPENCV)
BUILD_DIR := build

# make rules -------------------------------
CXX ?= g++
BUILD_DIR ?= ./build

LIBRARIES += opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc #opencv_imgcodecs

CXXFLAGS += $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS +=  $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(foreach includedir,$(LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(includedir)) $(foreach library,$(LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
SRC_DIRS += $(shell find * -type d -exec bash -c "find {} -maxdepth 1 \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.proto' \) | grep -q ." \; -print)
CXX_SRCS += $(shell find src/ -name "*.cpp")
CXX_TARGETS:=$(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o, $(CXX_SRCS))
ALL_BUILD_DIRS := $(sort $(BUILD_DIR) $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(SRC_DIRS)))

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROJECT_NAME)

.PHONY: $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
$(ALL_BUILD_DIRS):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
    @echo "CXX" $<
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(PROJECT_NAME): $(CXX_TARGETS)
    @echo "CXX/LD" $@
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIB)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf $(CXX_TARGETS)
    @rm -rf $(PROJECT_NAME)
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to modify next lines

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := ../../third_party/opencv/include/ include
LIBRARY_DIRS := ../../third_party/opencv/lib/ lib
```

Or second different way is to add `-I` and `-L` options to next lines

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -fopenmp -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -I../../third_party/opencv/include/
LDFLAGS := -fopenmp -Wl,-rpath,./lib -L../../third_party/opencv/lib/
```

Comment: emm... It seems does not work. I tried both. The compilation succeeded. But when I check its dependency, it still links to the system version.

Comment: @pfc Have you tried to rebuild your project from scratch? Because maybe it reused currently build options or files. Delete all build temporary files. Also it may be the case that your path for include and libraries is not correct. E.g. maybe you need to provide full absolute path instead of relative, try that! Because if your path is incorrect then build system falls back to system path version silently.